# Debug a file on virtual Vagrant box with Xdebug

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a Vagrant virtual machine, with a website running on it, on my MacBook.

I would like to inspect what is in a variable called $logs. I have set the cookie in my browser using the Chrome extension, and I am listening for PHP debug connections, and I have set a breakpoint. If I select the 'Run' menu and click 'Debug sitelog.module', I get some errors.

I'm not sure how to configure this? My ultimate goal is to inspect the contents of $logs. Thanks.

Comment: Did you already define the path mapping? Also can you show us your xdebug.ini

Answer (score 1):

I do not use cookies anymore for debugging as I found easier to debug by enabling [remote debugging](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) in xdebug.

In any case I suggest that you first create a PHP Web application and define a Server for that web application. To do this:

1. With the Navigation bar visible (View | Navigation Bar), the available run/debug configurations are displayed in the run/debug configuration selector in the Run area.

[image]

2. In the Run/Debug Configuration dialog box, click + (add) on the toolbar. The drop-down list shows the default run/debug configurations. Select the desired configuration type (ie: PHP Web Application).
3. Set up a server for this configuration by clicking on the ... icon next to the Server dropdown.

[image]

4. On the Servers configuration, fill in the name, host and port and check the **Use path mappings** checkbox.
5. Define your path mapping, by selecting on the left side (your host machine) the desired path and then providing the path to the same location in your guest (press enter on the input field once you define the path for the guest machine).

[image]

With this you should be able to debug using the XDEBUG cookie. If you would like to try the remote debugging option (which IMO is much simpler) then add this to your xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.auto_trace="0"
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/vagrant"
xdebug.trace_output_name="trace.%c"
xdebug.trace_format="2"
xdebug.trace_options="0"
xdebug.collect_includes="1"
xdebug.collect_params="0"
xdebug.collect_return="0"
xdebug.collect_vars="0"
xdebug.default_enable="1"
xdebug.extended_info="1"
xdebug.manual_url="http://www.php.net"
xdebug.max_nesting_level="256"
xdebug.show_error_trace="0"
xdebug.show_exception_trace="0"
xdebug.show_local_vars="0"
xdebug.show_mem_delta="1"
xdebug.dump.COOKIE="NULL"
xdebug.dump.ENV="NULL"
xdebug.dump.FILES="NULL"
xdebug.dump.GET="NULL"
xdebug.dump.POST="NULL"
xdebug.dump.REQUEST="NULL"
xdebug.dump.SERVER="NULL"
xdebug.dump.SESSION="NULL"
xdebug.dump_globals="1"
xdebug.dump_once="1"
xdebug.dump_undefined="0"
xdebug.overload_var_dump="2"
xdebug.profiler_enable="0"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/vagrant"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%p"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger="0"
xdebug.profiler_append="0"
xdebug.profiler_aggregate="0"
xdebug.remote_enable="1"
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="192.168.33.1"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.remote_autostart="1"
xdebug.remote_log=""
xdebug.idekey=""
xdebug.var_display_max_data="512"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth="2"
xdebug.var_display_max_children="128"
```

Make sure you adjust the remote_host ip if needed. Once you save this changes to your xdebug.ini, all you need to do to start debugging is to enable the **Start listening for PHP Debug Connections** icon (looks like a telephone).

[image]

Reference:

[How to set up Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

Comment: I, naturally, have several projects to debug with Xdebug. Do I need to provide separate configuration for every project, or is this just a one-time set-up which will work for every project?

Comment: Depends on how you structured your projects, if each project has it's own vagrant box, then you should setup individual projects for each box. But if all your projects are within the same shared folder you could also use one configuration for all.

Comment: On 'local' all my projects are under `User/PhpstormProjects/project1/`...`User/PhpstormProjects/project2/` which map to `/var/www/project1`...`/var/www/project2` on my vagrant box.

Comment: And are all of this projects on the same vagrant box? if so then you could set up the mapping like this: `User/PhpstormProjects/`-> `/var/www/`

Comment: So, is your solution, above, intended to squash the error in the bottom left of the very first image in my question?

Comment: Yes, although I cant see the images in your question anymore. This setup works, give it a try.